# Syntax error from CMD and Aptana 3.0

Tags: python, syntax, cmd, aptana

I just installed Python 3.3.2 with Windows Installer. Tried to test with "Hello World", and keep getting the following error(s) - from the command line OR Aptana Studio 3: (I did check out an earlier answer to an almost identical post. However, I can't seem to get this thing to work; am not sure if everything is configured right; CMD and from within Aptana Pydev env. -works fine on numerical operations...just not on anything else (string operations, etc.)

```
CMD:
>>> print "Hello World"
 File "<stdin>", line 1
 print "Hello World"
        ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Aptana 3:
File "<stdin>", line 1
 print "Hello World"
        ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
 ERROR: Module could not be imported [filepath], etc..etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.x, [`print`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print) was converted from a keyword to a built-in.  Meaning, you now have to call it:

```
>>> print "Hello World"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "Hello World"
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
>>> print("Hello World")  # Note the parenthesis
Hello World
>>>
```